# firefox and safari do not read some of a css file - not on localhost

Tags: html, css, angular, browser, styles

I am building an angular web app, my styles works perfectly in all browsers on a localhost but when I uploaded it on the server some styles did not work in firefox & safari.

in devtools all styles are loaded perfectly but some of them applied and others are not.
I imported all my styles in a file called style.css and what confused me is that the imported styles worked but the style inside style.css did not!

everything works fine in chrome
there is no errors neither in the console nor in the dev server.

all my imports are like this:

```
@import url('SOME RELATIVE LINK');
```

and I tried two ways of import the style.css
first in index.html like:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

and the other is inside styles list in angular.json

Any ideas?.

**EDIT:**
I've discovered that the browsers which are not displaying properly have added `media="print"` to my link tag automatically
but why that happens?

Comment: Perhaps the class names and id overlap in your main css file and in a separate one. In this case, the properties specified last will be applied. Need to isolate styles in file style.css

Comment: @AndreiFedorov I have already checked that, also the class name does not appear at all in the styles tab in devtools

Comment: ok, maybe you don't have access to the file, wrong path.

Comment: the file is loaded in network tab and the styles work in chrome perfectly

Comment: have you found out what was the reason?